# four knights puzzle in prolog

Tags: prolog, puzzle

the problem is to exchange 2 black knights positions with two white knights in a 3x3 chessboard,see the link http://www.puzzles.com/puzzleplayground/FourKnights/FourKnights.htm
i have to make Prolog give me at least one solution, and i am totally lost after these steps.

```
%mouvement possibilities
mouv(2,1).
mouv(-2,1).
mouv(2,-1).
mouv(-2,-1).
mouv(1,2).
mouv(-1,2).
mouv(1,-2).
mouv(-1,-2).
%conditions for valid mouvement

%not going out of the small chessboard
pos(X,Y):- X<4 ,X>0,Y<4,Y>0.

%free position
%????????

%initial positions
kgt(b,3,1).
kgt(b,3,3).
kgt(w,1,3).
kgt(w,1,1).
%mouv knight

%???
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3):

A simple (and inefficient) way could apply to a piece a valid move, and iterate til the required position appears. Of course we should avoid to repeat an already visited position, as this would lead to an infinite loop.

Then we need a way to represent this search space. A list of boards it's the obvious choice.

A board could be a sorted list of pieces, handy when it come to see if we reached the target position, and the board after move isn't already been visited.

```
puzzle :-
  setof(kgt(C,X,Y), kgt(C,X,Y), InitialBoard),
  apply_moves([InitialBoard], Boards),
  maplist(writeln, Boards).

apply_moves([Board|Visited], Solution) :-
  move_knight(Board, Moved),
  not_visited(Moved, Visited),
  Next = [Moved,Board|Visited],
  (  is_target(Moved)
  -> Solution = Next
  ;  apply_moves(Next, Solution)
  ).

move_knight(Board, Moved) :-
  select(kgt(C,X,Y), Board, B1),
  ...

is_target(Board) :-
  ...

not_visited(Moved, Visited) :-
  \+ memberchk(Moved, Visited).
```

See if you can fill the ellipsis.